# How to show the editor rather than the approver/(power automate user) in the Version History

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning

I have a list in SP online which needs admin approvals. After the admin approve the change, some calculations are done and some fields will be populated in the Power Automate.

Mohsen here is the admin who also developed the power automate. Mohs is the test user with limited ability.

Unfortunately,  whenever a user changes something and the admin approves it then the name of the admin appears on the version history. The version history does not show the name of the user who initiated the change.

See below (Modified by, Version Status, Created by):

1-Mohs (user) created a record that needs admin approval.
[image]

**By the way, why edited by is not empty?**

2- Admin (Mohsen) receive an email and approve it. Power automate does some calc and updates some columns.

[image]

3- Use (Mohs) changes another thing

[image]

4 -Admin (Mohsen) receive an email and approve it. Powwer automate does some calc and updates some columns.

[image]

Now the version history is:

[image]

As shown "Modified by" is the admin username (i.e. Mohsen), not the user who actually edited the item (i.e. Mohs), **so is there an easy way to fix this issue and see the name of the user who edited the draft not the name of the admin?**

And the version control settings are:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the expected behavior when you enable content approval, regardless of the setting.

The Approver would be the last one to actually do the modification since it changes the Approval Status of the list item.

This happens no matter if you do the Approval task using flow or manually via the list menu.